# Make camera follow that can fly around a sphere at a constant height and speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, orbit

I need to make a script that can make my maincamera fly around a sphere at a constant height and speed. I need to write it in c# and I'm kinda new to that, so I need some help.

So far I have just wrote a script that orbits around the object, but I want to control the camera with WASD.

This is my orbit-script so far

```
public class CameraOrbit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target = null;  
    public bool orbitY = false;

    void Start () 
    {
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (target != null) 
        {
            transform.LookAt(target.transform);
            if(orbitY)
            {
                transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that you want to control the camera with WASD? Are you talking about rotating or translating the camera with WASD?

Comment: I have a sphere, and on top of that I have a bigger invisible sphere that I want to represent a camera path. I want to fly around in that path, but always focusing the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options how to do this:

option #1 is the way you started

option #2: instead of rotating the camera around the sphere center, you can make the camera a child node of a node in the sphere center and then just change the euler angles of this parent node:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateChild : MonoBehaviour
{
   void Update()
   {
      if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.W ) )
         transform.Rotate( 1, 0, 0 );
      if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.S ) )
         transform.Rotate( -1, 0, 0 );
      if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.A ) )
         transform.Rotate( 0, -1, 0 );
      if( Input.GetKey( KeyCode.D ) )
         transform.Rotate( 0, 1, 0 );
   }
}
```

use this on a node in sphere center. make the camera a child of this node.

[image]

the sphere with scale 5:

[image]

the parent of the camera with attached script RotateChild:

[image]

this works 100% - i tested it :)

Comment: Thanks! 
Im so slow today tho, cant figure out the rest of the script im trying to attach to my camera -


using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FlyingCamera2 : MonoBehaviour {

 

 
 void Update () {

 
  Vector3 eulerAngles = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
   eulerAngles.x += 10;
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
   eulerAngles.x -= 10;
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
   eulerAngles.y += 10;
  if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
   eulerAngles.y -= 10;
      transform.rotation.eulerAngles = eulerAngles;
}

Comment: attach this script to a game object in sphere center. make the camera game object a child of this game object at a distance outside the sphere - like on the picture. that is everything you have to do.

Comment: Im getting "Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.rotation'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable"

Comment: Sorry for bump, but Im stuck. When Im using your script my camera just stays at the same position and not moving around

Comment: @user1769644 - if you do everything exactly as i did, it should work 100% - you have the whole script now :)